# Jupyter Notebook throwing Setx Error

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, setx

I opened Jupyter Notebook for the first time going to lay down some code only to be met with a password prompt. Seemed odd because I've never opened it on this PC and it doesn't prompt me for a password on my laptop. I took to the Google Machine for an answer how to disable the password, which was the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file to which (supposedly) I was to enter the following command `c.NotebookApp.token = u''`

Now the browser window opens up with

```
Invalid number of parameters
Invalid number of parameters
Invalid number of parameters
Invalid number of parameters
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.
Invalid number of parameters
Invalid number of parameters
Invalid number of parameters
Invalid number of parameters
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.
```

I even went so far as to uninstall Anaconda entirely, then reinstalled, and this error is still popping up.

What the ever loving `(*&%(*&^` did I do, how do I fix it, and why on this beautiful Earth does eve

```
In[140]: frame.reindex(index = ['a','b','c','d'],columns = states).ffill()

Out[142]:

Texas   Utah    California

a   1.0 NaN 2.0

b   1.0 NaN 2.0

c   4.0 NaN 5.0

d   7.0 NaN 8.0rything involving code have to be so god-damned complicated?
```